# Jordan form of linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

I'm trying to find all the possibles Jordan normal form of a linear map called $T$: $\mathbb{Q}^3$ → $\mathbb{Q}^3$ such that $(T^7+2I)(T^2+3T+2I)^2=0$.

So I am a little confuse because I know that to find the Jordan normal form I need the eigenvalues and the eigenvector of the linear transformation. But how can i find the matrix associated with T?

Comment: what's $Q$?....

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is the field of rational numbers, sorry, I didn't know I could write it with the appropriate tag.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3810583/jordan-form-of-linear-operator for some ideas.